# Unable to fetch data from relational table using laravel with() method

Tags: json, laravel-8, relational-database, laravel-api

I have table "Jobs" having a field called "empids". we are storing comma separated employee ids in this field, for ex. 1,12,56. I am trying to return JSON using with() method by making belongsTo relation ship between Job and employee models. There are more relation ship tables working fine with Jobs table using belongsTo as they are perfectly matching forien_key and index_key.

**Below is my laravel code**

```
// Get Job function:
       $emps = job::where('id',$id)->where('compid',$compid)->pluck('empids');
        $jobs = job::with(['jobcustomer'=>function ($q) use ($compid){
            $q->where('deleted_at',null)->where('compid',$compid);
        }])
        ->with(['jobcustomeraddress'=>function ($q) use ($compid){
            $q->where('deleted_at',null)->where('compid',$compid);
        }])
        ->with(['jobdetails'=>function ($q) use ($compid){
            $q->where('deleted_at',null)->where('compid',$compid);
        }])
        ->with(['jobemps'=>function ($q) use ($emps) { $q->whereIn('id',$emps); }])
        ->where('id',$id)->where('compid',$compid)->orderBy('id')->get();
        return $jobs;

//In Job Model:
public function jobemps()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(employee::class);
    }
```

**Below is what i am receiving as JSON. "Jobemps" are null**

```
[
    {
        "id": 71,
        "invid": "3",
        "segid": "9",
        "segname": "segment # 9",
        "due": "Upon start of work",
        "empids": "1,2,12",
        "invcurrstatus": null,
        "customer_id": 7,
        "custaddresse_id": 48,
      
        "jobcustomer": {
            "id": 7,
            "fname": "fawaz",
            "lname": "chughtai",
            "dname": "lat long",
            "email": "amjad@aiminsight.com",
        },
        "jobcustomeraddress": {
            "id": 48,
            "customer_id": 7,
            "street": "82 NJ-23",
            "city": "Hamburg",
            "state": "NJ",
            "zip": "07419-1400",
            "unit": null,
        },
        "jobdetails": [
            {
                "id": 351,
                "job_id": 71,
                "invid": "3",
                "segid": "9",
                "itemsec": 1,
                "invitem_id": 1,
                "itemname": "Service Call",
                "itemunit": "Each",
                "itemcost": 0,
                "itemprice": 69,
                "itemqty": 1,
                "itemtotal": 69,
            },
            {
                "id": 352,
                "job_id": 71,
                "invid": "3",
                "segid": "9",
                "itemsec": 2,
                "invitem_id": 2,
                "itemname": "Repair - Unclog toilet",
                "itemdesc": "Unclog a toilet. Must be reasonably accessible.",
                "itemunit": "Each",
                "itemcost": 0,
                "itemprice": 71,
                "itemqty": 1,
                "itemtotal": 71,
            }
        ],
        "jobemps": null
    }
]
```

**I am looking for jobemps as:**

```
"jobemps": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "abc",
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "efg",
            },
            {
                "id": 56,
                "name": "xyz",
            }
        ],
```

Error i am receiving is `select * from employees where 0 = 1 and id in (1,2,12)`

I dont know how to remove `where 0 = 1`
Please guide, Thanks

Comment: I think this is a bad design of table when doing a relationship. Correct me if I am wrong, you can't do relationship if you are designing the table like that. 

my suggestion is either you add another set of table to hold the employee information that connects to job.

relationship needs the unique keys in order to connect with each other.

Comment: I agree, but right now we need a solution to cop up this situation, creating new table for Job employees will cost us alot!

Comment: Any work around, any other way, any Raw query will help us. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK So based on Pemba Tamang's answer, it does solved the issue, here is the 100% working code with little fixes in Pemba's code

```
$emps = (job::where('id',$id)->where('compid',$compid)->first())->empids;
        $emps = explode(',',$emps);
        
        $jobs = job::with(['jobcustomer'=>function ($q) use ($compid){
            $q->where('deleted_at',null)->where('compid',$compid);
        }])
        ->with(['jobcustomeraddress'=>function ($q) use ($compid){
            $q->where('deleted_at',null)->where('compid',$compid);
        }])
        ->with(['jobdetails'=>function ($q) use ($compid){
            $q->where('deleted_at',null)->where('compid',$compid);
        }]) 
        ->where('id',$id)->where('compid',$compid)->first();
        

        $jobemps = employee::whereIn('id',$emps)->get();
        $data['job'] = $jobs;
        $data['jobemps'] = $jobemps;
        return $data;
```

Now i dont know if I should Mark Pemba's answer as accepted or mine, or may be Pemba corrects his answer so that I mark his answer as accepted. Thanks Pemba

Answer (score 1):

I think there doesnot exist relationship between job and employees according to your table structure. so creating relationship function is of no use.
$emps = job::where('id',$id)->where('compid',$compid)->pluck('empids');
convert $emps result to array.

since you want the query result attached with jobs u can attach an array like this

```
$emps = job::where('id',$id)->where('compid',$compid)->pluck('empids')->toArray();
        $jobs = job::with(['jobcustomer'=>function ($q) use ($compid){
            $q->where('deleted_at',null)->where('compid',$compid);
        }])
        ->with(['jobcustomeraddress'=>function ($q) use ($compid){
            $q->where('deleted_at',null)->where('compid',$compid);
        }])
        ->with(['jobdetails'=>function ($q) use ($compid){
            $q->where('deleted_at',null)->where('compid',$compid);
        }]) 
        ->where('id',$id)->where('compid',$compid)->first();
        

$jobemps=Employee::whereIn('id',$emps)->get();
$data['data'] = $jobs;
$data['jobemps'] = $jobemps;
return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//In Job Model:
public function jobemps()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(employee::class, null);
}
```

**Change your relationship to above, what it does is that it makes your relationship optional.**

The belongsTo method generates a SQL statement that retrieves the related model using a join query. The SQL statement includes a condition that links the foreign key of the current model to the primary key of the related model. However, if the foreign key value is null, the join query will not produce any results.

In some cases, the belongsTo method may generate a SQL statement that includes a condition where 0 = 1. This happens when the foreign key value is not set or is set to null, and the relationship is set to not be optional. In this case, the join query is designed to not return any results because the related model is required and the foreign key is not set.

Comment: nope, its still the same
`{
        "query": "select * from employees where 0 = 1 and id in (?)",
        "bindings": [
            "1,2,12"
        ],
        "time": 0.22
    }`